# Editing GTK theme (adding a border)

Tags: themes, gtk, customization

I am using a GTK theme which I love except that it doesn't have borders around the windows. If I am on a web page (for example) with a white background and my wallpaper is white I don't know where the web page starts. What is worse, sometimes that type of thing happens with other windows, where I can't tell where the one window start and the other ends.

Is there a way to edit GTK themes? More specifically, is there a way to edit a theme so that it will display a border around windows?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The window border width is actually set by the [Metacity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metacity) theme. You can either change the Metacity theme *(System ➜ Preferences ➜ Appearance ➜ Theme ➜ Customize ➜ Window Border)* to one that has a window border or [edit](http://developer.gnome.org/doc/tutorials/metacity/metacity-themes.html) the Metacity theme you are using right now.

Metacity theme files are located in `~/.themes/<theme name>/metacity-1/` and `/usr/share/themes/<theme name>/metacity-1/`.

Edit your theme's `metacity-theme-1.xml` file and
change all values `left_width`,`right_width` and `bottom_height` to something higher than `0`.

```
<distance name="left_width" value="2"/>
<distance name="right_width" value="2"/>
<distance name="bottom_height" value="2"/>
```

Comment: Looks like you also have to restart gnome for the changes to take affect. Thank you so much. This made my day.

Comment: @cdagh You don't need to restart gnome btw, just switch to a different theme, and then switch back.