# How can I edit GTK+ 3 themes to remove the window borders?

Tags: themes, customization, gtk3

Just like it is in the Zukini and Zukitwo shell themes, I want to edit the Ambiance theme and remove window borders.

Here are some screenshots:

GNOME terminal

- [Ambiance](http://imageshack.us/f/269/borderjb.png)
- [Zukini](http://imageshack.us/f/683/noborder.png)

GVIM

- [Ambiance](http://imageshack.us/f/85/gvimborder.png/)
- [Zukini](http://imageshack.us/f/259/gvimnoborder.png/)

Comment: Related (though this question is for an older version of GTK): http://askubuntu.com/q/27789/18612

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned, if you are experiencing a similar issue please [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with details pertaining to your problem. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, please flag the question explaining that. I am flagging this for closure. Regards,