# Ubuntu 22 Gnome dark theme window border

Tags: 22.04, themes, customization

On the default Ubuntu Gnome light theme there is white border around window, and shade effect - it is easy to spot how large window is and where are its edges.

On the dark theme multiple overlapping windows are visually mixed together and it is very hard to spot where is the edge of each window. Possibly there is a shade but on the dark theme it is not seen even if exists.

is it possible somehow to specify the color of the window border? For example to put some lighter color like whitish or some other light color to be in contrast to dark windows.

Comment: That is determined by the GTK theme in use. For GTK4 applications, that will be controlled by libadwaita.

Comment: figured that out but I am no expert on how to tweak some existing theme to modify this particular property

Comment: figured out that it is possibly done by css that can be found in theme dirs

Comment: If you have a solution, answer your own question, please.

Comment: I wish I know the solution, I have not even a hint where to look for eventual resolution. Unfortunately I did not find obvious place in CSS that may indicate how to hack window border. First mention hints the solution may be in the code (i.e. it is not event done in external CSS) and for that there shall be some more knowledgeable person who knows gnome internally to point to eventual solution. I can only wait for someone like that.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/27789/editing-gtk-theme-adding-a-border?rq=1 is talking about it but I cannot find appropriate place to try what was suggested - does not seem to be the same

Comment: https://gnome.pages.gitlab.gnome.org/libadwaita/doc/1.2/named-colors.html#helper-colors

and there is no customizable foreground window  border color even if someone builds this lib from scrach. This is somewhat discouraging. Can we have open system?